# Как сохранить объект Yandex Map (API 2.1) в базе данных?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как в API 2.1 получить следующее:

1. клик по объекту на карте вызывает балун, в котором есть кнопка редактирования объекта
2. клик по кнопке редактирования вызывает функцию редактирования объекта
3. клик по кнопке сохранить вызывает сохранение данных об объекте в базе mysql

Благодарен любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: Что конкретно не получается и что уже работает?

Comment: пока даже не понимаю как это сделать (опыта нет) какой нибудь пример бы не помешал. а может быть и заплатил бы кому нибудь за реализацию. На выходе должно получится это: http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/sozdaem-redaktor-yandeks-kart-chast-1

Answer (score 1):

После нажатия на кнопку редактирования сохраняйте координаты балуна (или координаты точки клика). После нажатия на кнопку "сохранить" отправляйте координаты на сервер и сохраняйте в базу серверным скриптом. При необходимости можнотакже сохранить текущий масштаб карты.